# Sorted Event form transformation puzzle

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I came across an algorithmic puzzle as following:

Given an array of events in the form of (name, start time, end time)
e.g.

(a, 1, 6)
(b, 2, 4)
(c, 7, 8)
...

The events are sorted based on their start time. I was asked to transform the event into another form (name, time),

e.g.
(a, 1)
(b, 2)
(b, 4)
(a, 6)
(c, 7)
(c, 8)

Notice that each event is now broken into two events, and they are required to be sorted by time.

The most naive way is O(n log n), and I thought of several other ways, but non of them is faster than O(n log n).

Anybody know the most time and space efficient way of solving this?

Answer (score 2):

Sweep time from beginning to end, maintaining a priority queue of the end times of active events, whose top element is compared repeatedly to the begin time of the next event. This is O(n log k), where k is the maximum number of simultaneous events, with extra space usage of O(k) on top of the input and output. I implemented something similar in C++ for this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25694591/2144669 .

Comment: A good solution. Worst case is still O(n log n), which will occur if you have something like `(a, 1, 10),(b, 2, 9),(c, 3, 8)`, (i.e. n simultaneous events), but if the data isn't pathological this will work well.

Comment: Upvoted because it's good theory. I'd check that it's actually faster in practice though since many modern sort implementations handle nearly-sorted-already data efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

This can be proven to be just as time consuming as regular sorting.

For example, suppose I want to sort N positive numbers. I could convert that to this problem of sorting N tuples of the form (a1, 0, num1), (a2, 0, num2), ..., (aN, 0, numN). This would yield a sorted result (a1, 0), (a2, 0), ..., (aN, 0), (aSorted1, numSorted1), ..., (aSortedN, numSortedN). Hence we would get {numSorted1, ..., numSortedN}. It is proven that the last sort should take at least O(N*Log(N)), so you can't get any better than that in the general case.

However, if you say that the start times are unique, there may be some other optimizations to the problem.

EDIT: We are using additional space of O(N) here but I think there can be an argument made with that case. However it is not as rigorous an answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Really efficient implementation depends on some limitation, applied to your data.
But, in general, following method can sort your list for O(N), and memory 2N:

```
1. Create struct like:

struct data {
  int timestamp;  // Event timestamp
  int orig_index; // Index of original event in the input array
}

2. Copy data from the input array into array of structures [1]. 
   Each original event is copied into two structs "data". This is O(N).

3. Sort resulting array with RadixSort, by field "timestamp".
   This is again O(N): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort

4. Create output array, and restore names from original array by 
   index "orig_index", if needed. Again O(N).
```

Answer (score 0):

No algorithm is more time efficient, since the sorting problem, which has a tight lower bound of omega(nlogn) is reducible to this problem (to sort an array, pick any group of start times etc.)
As for space complexity, [Heapsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort), which uses O(1) auxillary space and O(nlogn) time, is probably the best worst-case algorithm.